# Three.js shadow too detailed

Tags: three.js, shadow, renderer, light

I have a loaded 3D object and I want a shadow not as detailed as in the image.

[image]

I'd want a shadow with softer edges, like in the example: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=shadow#webgl_shadowmap_pcss.
I also tried to load a png as shadow texture, but that's not shown.
Here's my code of normal shadow by directional light:

```
const larghContenitore = $( window ).width();
const altContenitore = $( window ).height();

let shadowGroup, renderTarget, renderTargetBlur, shadowCamera, cameraHelper, depthMaterial, horizontalBlurMaterial, verticalBlurMaterial;
let plane, blurPlane, fillPlane;

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
renderer.setSize( larghContenitore, altContenitore );
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
renderer.gammaFactor = 2.2;
renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
        
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, larghContenitore / altContenitore, 1, 1000 );
camera.position.set( 0, 50, zoom );

scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color().setHSL( 0.6, 0, 1 );
scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( scene.background, 1, 5000 );

const axisHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper(100);
scene.add(axisHelper);

const ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff, 0.3 );
scene.add( ambient );

const dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 1 );
dirLight.color.setHSL( 0, 0, 1 );
dirLight.position.set( 10, 50, 10 );
dirLight.castShadow = true;
dirLight.shadow.mapSize.width = 2048;
dirLight.shadow.mapSize.height = 2048;

const d = 200;
dirLight.shadow.camera.top = d;
dirLight.shadow.camera.bottom = - d;
dirLight.shadow.camera.left = - d;
dirLight.shadow.camera.right = d;
dirLight.shadow.camera.far = 3500;
dirLight.shadow.bias = 0.0001;
dirLight.shadow.normalBias = 0.5;
dirLight.shadow.darkness = 0.1;
dirLight.shadow.camera.castShadow = true;
dirLight.shadow.radius = 50;

scene.add( dirLight );

const dirLightHelper = new THREE.DirectionalLightHelper( dirLight, 10 );
scene.add( dirLightHelper );

const geo = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 10000, 10000 );
const mat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xffffff } );
mat.color.setHSL( 0, 0, 0.7 );

plane = new THREE.Mesh(geo, mat);
plane.position.y = - 33;
plane.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;
plane.receiveShadow = true;
plane.material.opacity = 0.5;
scene.add(plane);

const controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
controls.enablePan = false;
controls.maxPolarAngle = ( Math.PI / 2.5 );
controls.minPolarAngle = ( Math.PI / 3 );
controls.minDistance = 48;
controls.maxDistance = maxZoom;
controls.enableZoom = true;
controls.update();

let product;

const matStdObjects = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ 
  color: '#ffffff', 
  roughness: 0.5, 
  metalness: 0.8
  //shininess: 80
});

matStdObjects.color.convertSRGBToLinear();

let loader = new FBXLoader();
loader.load( 'model/2021_01_26_DMT_EVO_R1_AR_200k.fbx', function ( object ) {
  let box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject( object );
  console.log( box.getSize() );
  
  let mesh = object.children;
  for (let i = 0; i < mesh.length; i++) {
    mesh[i].material = matStdObjects;
  }
            
  object.position.set( 0, 5, 0 );
  //object.rotation.set( 0, 0, Math.PI / 2 );
  
  object.traverse( function ( child ) {
    if ( child.isMesh ) {
      child.castShadow = true;
      child.receiveShadow = false;
      child.flatshading = true;
    }
  });
  
  object.castShadow = true;  
  
  product = object;
  scene.add( object );
    
  animate();
  
});
```

Is it possibile to "simplify" the object shadow? Or it's better loading a png as shadow texture? And  in case, how can I do that?

Comment: Can you please give the approach from this example a try? https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_shadow_contact

Comment: @Mugen87 I tried to use that approach, but it doesn't work. In the example the objects are geometry shapes, but I need a loaded object and shadows are obtained in a different way

Comment: Maybe I made it wrong, but how can I reproduce the example approach in my case? That's what I'm looking for.